# Android VM reboot after application crashing on Android 6.0.0

Tags: java, android, crashlytics

I got an error with my application on Android 6.0.0 (I use genimotion).

I don't understand why I get this error. It's works correctly on Android 4.4.

When I get this error, the VM reboot... That's strange.

I cannot debug my code :/

```
07-12 04:24:59.289 14686-14686/fr.xxx.xxx.dev E/DisplayManager: Could not get display information from display manager.
                                                                            android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                                at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                                                at android.hardware.display.IDisplayManager$Stub$Proxy.getDisplayInfo(IDisplayManager.java:254)
                                                                                at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal.getDisplayInfo(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:119)
                                                                                at android.view.Display.updateDisplayInfoLocked(Display.java:816)
                                                                                at android.view.Display.getState(Display.java:784)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:452)
                                                                                at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
                                                                                at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                                at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
                                                                                at fr.xxx.xxx.service.WebServicesManager.checkSession(WebServicesManager.java:132)
                                                                                at fr.xxx.xxx.ui.activities.AbstractActivity.onStart(AbstractActivity.java:55)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-12 04:24:59.291 14686-14686/fr.xxx.xxx.dev D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-12 04:24:59.293 14686-14758/fr.xxx.xxx.dev E/CrashlyticsCore: An error occurred in the fatal exception logger
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.CommonUtils.getBatteryLevel(CommonUtils.java:424)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeSessionEvent(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:994)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeFatal(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:395)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:298)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.access$200(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:56)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$7.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:278)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$7.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:275)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
                                                                                 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-12 04:24:59.299 14686-14758/fr.xxx.xxx.dev E/Fabric: Failed to flush to session app file.
                                                                    java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
                                                                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:498)
                                                                        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CodedOutputStream.refreshBuffer(CodedOutputStream.java:668)
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CodedOutputStream.flush(CodedOutputStream.java:678)
                                                                        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.CommonUtils.flushOrLog(CommonUtils.java:768)
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeSessionApp(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:889)
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.doOpenSession(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:606)
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:301)
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.access$200(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:56)
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$7.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:278)
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$7.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:275)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
                                                                        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
                                                                        at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
                                                                        at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:271)
                                                                        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:313)
                                                                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:493)
                                                                        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186) 
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CodedOutputStream.refreshBuffer(CodedOutputStream.java:668) 
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CodedOutputStream.flush(CodedOutputStream.java:678) 
                                                                        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.CommonUtils.flushOrLog(CommonUtils.java:768) 
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeSessionApp(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:889) 
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.doOpenSession(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:606) 
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:301) 
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.access$200(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:56) 
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$7.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:278) 
                                                                        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$7.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:275) 
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75) 
                                                                        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30) 
                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
07-12 04:24:59.299 14686-14686/fr.xxx.xxx.dev E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
                                                                             java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fabric could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml. Add the following tag to your Application element 
                                                                                <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:178)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.executeSyncLoggingException(CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.java:44)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:275)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fabric could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml. Add the following tag to your Application element 
                                                                                <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
                                                                                 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.logErrorOrThrowException(ApiKey.java:110)
                                                                                 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.getValue(ApiKey.java:61)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionDataWriter.getSessionAppOrgSize(SessionDataWriter.java:399)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionDataWriter.getSessionAppSize(SessionDataWriter.java:388)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionDataWriter.writeSessionApp(SessionDataWriter.java:71)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeSessionApp(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:882)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.doOpenSession(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:606)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:301)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.access$200(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:56)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$7.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:278)
                                                                                 at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$7.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:275)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
                                                                                 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-12 04:24:59.300 14686-14686/fr.xxx.xxx.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: fr.xxx.xxx.dev, PID: 14686
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.xxx.xxx.dev/fr.xxx.xxx.ui.activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:543)
                                                                                at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
                                                                                at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                                at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
                                                                                at fr.xxx.xxx.service.WebServicesManager.checkSession(WebServicesManager.java:132)
                                                                                at fr.xxx.xxx.ui.activities.AbstractActivity.onStart(AbstractActivity.java:55)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                             Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                                at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                                                at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:746)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:531)
                                                                                at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310) 
                                                                                at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85) 
                                                                                at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319) 
                                                                                at fr.xxx.xxx.service.WebServicesManager.checkSession(WebServicesManager.java:132) 
                                                                                at fr.xxx.xxx.ui.activities.AbstractActivity.onStart(AbstractActivity.java:55) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
07-12 04:24:59.300 14686-14686/fr.xxx.xxx.dev E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                                                            android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                                at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4425)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
                                                                                at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:289)
                                                                                at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                                                at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
07-12 04:24:59.300 14686-14686/fr.xxx.xxx.dev I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14686 SIG: 9
```